# How to parse an xml file line by line with C libexpat on Linux?

Tags: c, xml, linux

I am looking for how to parse an XML file via a C libexpat and Linux. I'm looking for the parse does not load the entire file contents in memory, I want the parse is done by reading the xml document line by line.

Is there anyone I can propose a method using expat?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: You could build your own state machine, or use a SAX parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML_Parse just does that. See the sample code below:

```
actual_size = fread(xmlData, 1, 32, fp);
while (actual_size > 0) {
    if (XML_Parse(parser, xmlData, actual_size, 0) == XML_STATUS_ERROR) {
        printf("%s at line %l\n",
                XML_ErrorString(XML_GetErrorCode(parser)),
                (long) XML_GetCurrentLineNumber(parser));
        return 1;
    }
    actual_size = fread(xmlData, 1, 32, fp);
}
```